# Issues in linking Hyperledger Explorer with fabricsample

Tags: hyperledger, transaction-log

Can anyone please mention the path or related details of the binary file, which is the actual ledger holding the immutable transaction log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to find path to actual ledger at:

```
/var/hyperledger/production/ledgersData
```

Comment: But I couldn't find such a path.

Comment: Are you looking inside peer container?

Comment: I was able to view the ledger. Thanks for the prompt reply.